Creating $\frac {\varepsilon_0} 2$ using surreal numbers
Does the quantity $\frac {\varepsilon_0} 2$ exist in surreal numbers, as a number which after being multiplied by 2 yields $\varepsilon_0$? If so, how is it constructed and how do you prove that the construction works?
My attempt at the construction goes:
$$\varepsilon_0 = \{\omega, \omega^\omega, \omega^{\omega^\omega}, ... \mid \varnothing \}$$
$$\text{For ordinal $\beta < \varepsilon_0$: } \; \varepsilon_0 - \beta = \{\omega, \omega^\omega, \omega^{\omega^\omega}, ...  \mid \forall k \in \mathbb{N} : \varepsilon_0 - \beta[k]\}$$
$$\frac {\varepsilon_0} 2 = \{\omega, \omega^\omega, \omega^{\omega^\omega}, ...  \mid \varepsilon_0 - \omega, \varepsilon_0 - \omega^\omega, \varepsilon_0 - \omega^{\omega^\omega}, ...\}$$
Then if we try multiplication by 2:
$$\{\omega, \omega^\omega, \omega^{\omega^\omega}, ...  \mid \varepsilon_0 - \omega, \varepsilon_0 - \omega^\omega, \varepsilon_0 - \omega^{\omega^\omega}, ...\}\{1 \mid \varnothing\} = \{X_L \mid X_R\}\{1 \mid \varnothing\}$$
$$= \{X_L 2 + \frac {\varepsilon_0} 2 - X_L \mid \frac {\varepsilon_0} 2 + X_R 2 - X_R\}$$
$$= \{\frac {\varepsilon_0} 2 + X_L \mid \frac {\varepsilon_0} 2 + X_R\}$$
$$= \{\frac {\varepsilon_0} 2 + X_L \mid \varepsilon_0 + \frac {\varepsilon_0} 2 - X_L\}$$
Then we argue that all elements of  $\frac {\varepsilon_0} 2 - X_L$ are positive, and all terms of the LHS are less then $\varepsilon_0$, both using some painful induction on the Cantor Normal Form, and therefore understand that $\varepsilon_0$ lies between the LHS and the RHS.
Questions:

Is my attempt correct on a high level? I basically manipulated the expressions as if they were expressions of real numbered variables, I think it's fine because surreal arithmetic satisfies commutativity and associativity?
Is there any simpler argument for my last paragraph other than a painful induction using the Cantor Normal Form?
How do you show that $\varepsilon_0$ is the "simplest" surreal number between the LHS and the RHS, to finally prove that multiplying my construction by 2 uniquely results in $\varepsilon_0$?

